# Creating a migration in knex.js is throwing an error

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I am trying to create a migration and it throws the following error

```
yarn run v1.6.0
(node:14212) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usabil
ity issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods in
stead.
$ babel-node node_modules/.bin/knex migrate:make create_linky_table
C:\Users\Sagar\Desktop\linky\api\node_modules\.bin\knex:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:656:28)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\Users\Sagar\Desktop\linky\lms-linky\api\node_modules\pi
rates\lib\index.js:88:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I have the following set up in my script in package.json

```
"knex": "babel-node --require ./node_modules/dotenv/config node_modules/.bin/knex --knexfile='src/knexfile.js'",
```

I am using the following code to create the migration

```
yarn knex make:migration create_linky_table
```

I am currently using windows and i came upon [this answer](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3750) . Could it be a windows issue?

Comment: do you already have an answer to this?

Answer (score 5):

What @Mikael Lepistö said is correct.

I faced similar issue while doing migration scripts on windows.

My previous command was:

```
babel-node node_modules/.bin/knex --knexfile src/database/knexfile.js migrate:latest
```

I changed it to:

```
babel-node node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js --knexfile src/database/knexfile.js migrate:latest
```

And the error has gone. May be changing the reference from `.bin/knex` to `/knex/bin/cli.js` will make the magic for youso give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `C:\Users\Sagar\Desktop\linky\api\node_modules\.bin\knex` script in windows is not JavaScript executable, but actually shell script wrapper in Windows. So when you try to use `babel-node` or `node` to execute it, node interpreter fails because you are trying to run `bash/sh` shell script with it.

Check out what is stored inside the `C:\Users\Sagar\Desktop\linky\api\node_modules\.bin\knex` script and if there is a way to override, which `node` interpreter is used, you can override it with `babel-node`. If there is no way to override it, you can just check out if it calls for example `node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js` and call directly that with `babel-node`.

I would check those out myself, but I don't have Windows node tools setup on this desktop.